# Width of 3rd level of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slide down menu. In HTML I have:

```
<menu>
    <li id="vysledky"><a href="#">Výsledky</a>
        <ul class="menu2">
            <li>2008
                <ul class="menu3">
                    <li><a href="#">21.08. - MMSR SCg</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">R SCOOechová Potôň SK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SCOOTER Brezová /Visonta/ HU</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2010</li>
            <li>2011<</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="forum"><a href="#" class="prvy"><span>Fórum</span></a></li>
</menu>
```

And now i want to automaticly set the width of each 3rd level of menu (menu3) by the longest text in it. So in this example the width of this .menu3 will be the width of text "SCOOTER Brezová /Visonta/ HU".

I can't use css because the width of menu2 is stable and if it will be longer than menu2 its set to width of menu2 (cascade)
So i would use javascript (jquery). I have this code:

```
      var i;
    var podm;

    $('menu>li').each(function() {
        podm = 0;
        if($(this).children('ul').size()) {
            $(this).each(function() {

                if($(this).children('ul').size()) {
            $(this).each(function() {

                podm++;
                    i = 60;
$(this).find('li a').each(function() {
    var w = $(this).text();
    $('#js').text(w);
    w = $('#js').width();
    if(w > i) {
        i = w;
    }
});
                $(this).find("ul.menu3").css("width");
                });
            }
            });
        }
    });
```

But this code works bad :-(.

Web: [Here](http://www.dark-project.cz/scooter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the width of the `menu3` ul to 345px which causes longer text to overlap. The Javascript just sets this width again.

```
<ul class="menu3" style="width: 345px; display: block; opacity: 0.13">
```

Try to remove the width specification and the jQuery code and check if it works. If you need a specific minimum width for the level 3 menu, you can use the `min-width` CSS attribute.

EDIT:
Ok, spotted it. The problem is the `position: relative` attribute in `.menu3`. The CSS for `.menu3` should look like this:

```
.menu3 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* This changed */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0px; /* This changed */
    background: #464646 url('3menu-po.png') repeat-y;
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Note the `position: absolute`. This takes the submenu out of the document flow and therefore it is not affected by the width set in `.menu2`.

Comment: Sorry, but where i set the width of menu3? I cant find the code you wrote on the page.

Comment: Sorry, it's set by the Javascript. It can be seen in Opera Dragonfly. How does the site change if you disable the Javascript that sets the width?

Comment: Now i delete my js script for calculating the width of 3rd menu. So you can see it on the web. Btw in css I use white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Wow. It works :-). Thank you very much. I should have guessed, such stupidity